# Switching OS by just switching M.2 SSD in my dell INSPIRON 5577?

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, dell-inspiron, m.2

I actually have a DELL laptop with a 100GB M.2 SSD with windows 10. All the OS partitions are in that disk. Also, the computer have a regular 1TB 7200r HDD that is used for DATA.

What I want to know:

If I buy another M.2 SSD, would I be able to install any other OS(example, Linux mint) without any problem and keep using the DATA HDD?

And Would I be able to go back to normal(boot with W10) if I just switch to the original M.2 SSD again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> If I buy another M.2 SSD, would I be able to install any other OS

Yes.

> Would I be able to go back to normal(boot with W10) if I just switch to the original M.2 SSD again?

Yes. But why over-complicate things that are (or should) be quite simple? Why go to such lengths - swapping hardware - and even buy expensive hardware when you can simply shrink the current Win10 partition to make space for the other OS?

The truth is with a SSD of 200GB you have plenty of space for two or more OSs. Just keep the secondary drive formatted as NTFS and it can be used by Windows or Linux.

Comment: Sorry.. my mistake. The M.2 is just 100GB. With only 20Gb available ( all software, games, work installed in DATA)

Comment: No problem. The answer is the same anyway. All software installed in DATA? So you're using 80GB for Windows system only? Something is very wrong already... But other than that this shouldn't even be a question. I recommend finding a professional to that for you.